# Conditional negative lookaheads

Tags: regex

Using regexp to match the string `([0-99]% loss)`, that is if the number inside is between `0` and `99`. However, if the text contains a special `codeword`, there shouldn’t be a match even if % < 100.

For instance, this one shall match: ✓

```
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
Packets: Sent = 100, Received = 1, Lost = 99 (99% loss)
```

But not these four: ✗

```
Test of codeword string:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)

Another codeword test:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 2, Lost = 2 (50% loss)

Final test:
Packets: Sent = 70, Received = 0, Lost = 70 (100% loss)

Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss)
Packets: Sent = 100, Received = 0, Lost = 100 (100% loss)
```

Currently i have written the regexp `\((?!100)\d+% loss\)` to catch the needed strings which do not contain the `codeword`, but am unable to expand the regexp to have it blocking the `codeword` if it’s present. I’m thinking of a conditional negative lookahead of some sort (like`(?!codeword)|\((?!100)\d+% loss\)`?), but how shall it look?

Comment: So the `codeword` isn't on the same line as the `% loss` match?

Comment: Correct, it will never be on the same line. But if it is present elsewhere in the string which is fed to the regexp engine, the whole string must be discarded even if it has a % lower than 100.

Comment: What is the tool you are using?

Comment: The engine will be PCRE.